# What does this complicated jQuery selector mean?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jrubyonrails

What does this jQuery selector means?

```
button[data-remote]:not(form button), button[data-confirm]:not(form button)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The button element is being selected using these two selectors listed in the jQuery documentation:

[[HasAttribute]](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)
[:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

This basically means that:

```
'button[data-remote]:not(form button)'
```

is looking for all buttons with a data attribute of 'data-remote' that are not buttons inside of forms.

The same logic goes for the other selector you listed as well.

Answer (score 2):

You beat me to it.  But yes basically it's looking for buttons that have the data- attributes of either data-remote or data-confirm that are not located within a form.